# Seeing Greek letters in RStudio when viewing data.frame

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, cyrillic

Out of nowhere when I look at my imported csv I see Greek alphabet (as seen in the example image).

- The csv file itself is in Latin, encoding shouldn't be the problem
- In the RStudio options I have English language
- When I copy the text and paste it, its in Latin alphabet again

[image: Example]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. BTW, I see *Greek* letters (and not *Cyrillic*), e.g. as **Φορεστ**…

Comment: Oh its Greek, sorry, I edited the question. I don't know how exactly I should provide MRE here. I could upload example csv. In R I am using simpe read.csv() function which until today worked perfectly fine. The same script yesterday showed normal Latin letters. Maybe I will try reinstall both R and RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to install "Dejavu Sans" font.